# SyntaxError occurs each time setInterval fires

Tags: javascript, syntax, timer, syntax-error, setinterval

I'm trying to write a simple AI for a game in JavaScript. (The game is not mine.) Here is the extent of my code so far for the AI:

```
function AIManager(grid) {
  this.events = {};
  this.grid = grid;

  setInterval(new function(){console.log("hello")}, 1000);
}
```

When I try to run the game, the console outputs "hello" a single time followed by

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

once per second, with no stack trace or line number attached to it. (When I set the interval to 1 ms instead of 1000 ms, this error printed every 1 ms, so it is definitely responding to the setInterval function.)

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening? I'm a bit of a javascript noob right now... Thanks!

Comment: Check your code here http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the `new` in this case.

`setInterval()` is expecting a `Function`, which the [`function` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) will already create.

```
setInterval(function(){console.log("hello")}, 1000);
// logs 'hello'
// logs 'hello'
// ...
```

The `"hello"` is logged once with `new` because it's invoking the `Function` immediately as a constructor.

```
var o = new function () {
    console.log("hello");
};
// logs "hello" during construction

console.log(typeof o); // "object"
```

And, the `SyntaxError` is likely because `setInterval()`, finding the argument isn't a `Function`, is converting the instance `Object` to a `String` that it can `eval`uate:

```
setInterval(new function () {
    this.toString = function () {
        return "console.log('foo');";
    };
}, 1000);
// logs 'foo'
// logs 'foo'
// ...
```

Note: Since timers (`setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`) aren't actually standardized, the behavior in the previous snippet may not be consistent between engines.

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it. So, if I understand it right, function(){} creates a method that constructs a function, and "new function(){}" creates an instance of that function. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected identifier is `{}`.

The result of the expression

```
new function() { console.log("hello"); }
```

is an empty object (`{}`) which you can verify that in your console. That empty object is then being passed into `setInterval` as the first argument:

```
setInterval({}, 1000);
```

`setInterval` [expects either a string or a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval), not an object. So, since `{}` isn't a function it's passing it into the `Function` constructor in an attempt to get a function that it can execute, a la:

```
new Function({})
```

The result of that statement is your uncaught `SyntaxError`.